# GroupBy + custom mode function in python-polars

Tags: python, python-polars

I need to apply a "custom" mode function to a groupBy object.
I'm able to groupBy and apply mode:

```
 df.with_columns(pl.col("X").mode().over(['Y', 'Z']).name.prefix("mode_"))
```

and that kind of approach gives me this kind of error:

```
 ComputeError: the length of the window expression did not match that of the group
```

due to the fact that some values of the "X" col are null (can't drop them).

I'm heading towards the a custom mode function that returns the mode whenever possible and None otherwise. Something like this:

```
  def custom_mode(x):
      return x.mode().iloc[0] if not x.mode().empty else None
```

but i'm open to different and smarter approaches.

Any help would be very much appreciated!

Comment: reproducible example please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just put `.first` before `.over`

```py
In [63]: df = pl.DataFrame({'a': [1,1,2,2,3], 'b': [1,1,1,1,2]})

In [64]: df.with_columns(pl.col('a').mode().first().over('b').name.prefix('mode_'))
Out[64]:
shape: (5, 3)
┌─────┬─────┬────────┐
│ a   ┆ b   ┆ mode_a │
│ --- ┆ --- ┆ ---    │
│ i64 ┆ i64 ┆ i64    │
╞═════╪═════╪════════╡
│ 1   ┆ 1   ┆ 1      │
│ 1   ┆ 1   ┆ 1      │
│ 2   ┆ 1   ┆ 1      │
│ 2   ┆ 1   ┆ 1      │
│ 3   ┆ 2   ┆ 3      │
└─────┴─────┴────────┘
```